# Store recent user’s searches

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I’m fetching data from GitHub API and I have a search and submit button.
So basically after each user search I want to store the search name to another page that I have built.
That is how I am getting the data:

```
const handleSubmit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputText}/repos`)
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      })
  };
```

*inputText* is basically what I want to store or the *e.target.value* otherwise from search component?

What is the best way to approach it?
Use local storage somehow or React useContext?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106152/19826504) will provide you more information about context/localStorage and when to choose what.
so basically you can save the data both ways, but it depends on what are you trying to achieve.